Find Outer Boundary Of A Non-Convex Self-Intersecting Polygon
Consider a self-intersecting non-convex polygon:
points = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {11, 4}, {-1, 4}, {4, .5}, {6, 7}, {7, 
0}, {10, 0}, {10, 6}, {0, 6}};

I need to find the polygon's outer boundary (in red):
boundary={{0,0},{2,0},{3.660194174757282,0.7378640776699029},{4,0.5},{4.138613861386139,0.9504950495049506},{6.701492537313434,2.0895522388059704},{7,0},{10,0},{10,3.555555555555556},{10,4},{10,6},{6.142857142857142,6},{6,7},{5.692307692307692,6},{5.692307692307692,6},{0,6},{0,4},{-1,4},{0,3.3000000000000003}};

{
Graphics@Thread@Line@Transpose[{points, RotateLeft@points}],
 Graphics@{Red, Thread@Line@Transpose[{boundary, RotateLeft@boundary}]}
}


WindingPolygon, OuterPolygon and their combinations fail:
{
Graphics@Thread@Line@Transpose[{#,RotateLeft@#}]&@WindingPolygon[points][[1]],
Graphics@Thread@Line@Transpose[{#,RotateLeft@#}]&@OuterPolygon[Polygon@points][[1]],
Graphics@Thread@Line@Transpose[{#,RotateLeft@#}]&@OuterPolygon[WindingPolygon[points]][[1]]
}


What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Apply my function contourPolygon on coordinates of a polygon. (output is already a polygon)
Use preset tms variable from @Anton answer.
contourPolygon[x_] := 
 Polygon[#[[1]][[First@FirstCase[#, _Rule, {#[[2]]}, All]]]] &@
  CrossingPolygon[x]

Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], Polygon[#], FaceForm[None], 
     EdgeForm[{Green}], contourPolygon[#]}] & /@ tms // 
 Multicolumn[#, Background -> Gray] &




Now we're talking

How come this CrossingPolygon functionality is not mentioned anywhere in documentation? CrossingPolygon[points][[2]] gives all that is necessary, but is somehow omitted Help.

@cvgmt Yes, but may not work for some special cases, like for example points {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}.

@cvgmt In fact your code does not work. Look at Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], CrossingPolygon[tm9] /. Rule[a_, b_] :> a}] or instead of tm9 use tm1 or tm2.

@Anton I agree, the second argument of output of CrossingPolygon is not well explained in the documentation. Also notice that code in cvgmt's comment above does not work as can be seen by code in my previous comment.

@cvgmt It still does not work with tm9. And why I would do that when my code already works correctly without any RegionBoundary?

#[[1]][[FirstCase[#[[2]], _List, #[[2]], All]]] works just as good.

points = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {11, 4}, {-1, 4}, {4, .5}, {6, 7}, {7, 
    0}, {10, 0}, {10, 6}, {0, 6}};

poly = Polygon@points;

pts = RegionUnion[poly, DiscretizeRegion@OuterPolygon@poly] // 
   MeshPrimitives[#, 0] & // Map[Apply[Sequence]]

Graphics[{Lighter@Yellow, Polygon@pts, Red, Point@pts, Black, 
  Line@(Join[pts, {First@pts}])}]



Using RegionBoundary:
pts = DiscretizeRegion[poly] // RegionBoundary // 
    MeshPrimitives[#, 0] & // Map[Apply[Sequence]];
fst = FindShortestTour[pts];
pts[[Last@fst]] // 
 Graphics[{Lighter@Green, Polygon@#, Red, Point@#}] &



RegionUnion[poly, OuterPolygon@poly] does not work on my system (WM 14.0 Windows).

In computing pts in the first set of codes, the following error occurs:
Part::partw: Part 2 of Line[{{{-1.,4.},{0.,3.3}},{{0.,0.},{2.,0.}},{{0.,3.3},{0.,0.}},{{3.66019,0.737864},{4.,0.5}},{{<<18>>,<<3>>},<<1>>},<<1>>,{{6.14286,6.},{6.42857,4.}},{{6.42857,4.},{6.70149,2.08955}},{{7.,0.},{10.,0.}},{{10.,3.55556},{11.,4.}}}] does not exist. "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"

Sorry about the omission. I have updated the first answer to include DiscretizeRegion.

RegionUnion[poly, DiscretizeRegion@OuterPolygon@poly] crashes on 14.0

I use v12.2 so can't say that I know how to fix/alter it for more recent versions.


We add a large Rectangle which contain the Polygon and use RegionDifference to clip the Polygon.

After that we use InnerPolygon to get the "boundary" desired region.

I test this method in version 12.2,12.3, 13.3.1,14.0 but does not work in 14.1, it is a bug of 14.1 since the result of RegionDifference is wrong.


rectangle = 
  Rectangle @@ 
   Transpose@CoordinateBounds[Transpose@RegionBounds[poly], 1.5];
regout = BoundaryMesh[rectangle];
reg = RegionDifference[regout, poly];
regin = InnerPolygon[reg];
{regout, Region@poly, reg}
Graphics[{Red, RegionBoundary[regin]}]


The correct result of RegionDifference should be (version 13.3.1 and 14.0 is right, version 12.2,12.3 and 14.1 is wrong)
For version 12.2 and 12.3, when we set poly = WindingPolygon[points, "NonzeroRule"]; then all the result is correct.




If we don't not want to use InnerPolygon, we can also extract the MeshCells in the region.

MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[reg], 
 MeshCells[reg, 1, "Multicells" -> True][[2]]]

or
BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[reg], 
  MeshCells[reg, 1, "Multicells" -> True][[2]]] // RegionBoundary



regin is EmptyRegion[2] on 14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024).

@A.Kato Since RegionDifference is wrong in version 14.1

For version 14.1, we have to use ImageMesh.  Clear[points, poly, rectangle, g]; points = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {11, 4}, {-1, 4}, {4, .5}, {6, 7}, {7,      0}, {10, 0}, {10, 6}, {0, 6}}; poly = WindingPolygon[points, "NonzeroRule"]; rectangle = Rectangle @@ Transpose@CoordinateBounds[points, .5]; g = Graphics[{rectangle, White, poly}] // ImageMesh; BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[g],    MeshCells[g, 1, "Multicells" -> True][[2]]] // RegionBoundary

@cvgmt ImageMesh does not give a precise solution.

@Anton That is why I just add a comments.

Here's a more generalized solution, based on @cvgmt's approach.
Toy models:
tm1={{-10,-5},{10,-5},{10,5},{-0.75,5},{-0.75,3},{2,3},{2,-3},{-2,-3},{-2,3},{0.75,3},{0.75,5},{-10,5}};
tm2={{-10,-5},{10,-5},{10,5},{0,4.5},{0,3.5},{2,3},{2,-3},{-2,-3},{-2,3},{0,3},{0,5},{-10,5}};
tm3={{-10,-5},{10,-5},{10,5},{0,4.5},{1,3.5},{2,3},{2,-3},{-2,-3},{-2,3},{0,3},{0,5},{-10,5}};
tm4={{-10,-5},{10,-5},{10,5},{0,5},{0,3},{2,3},{2,-3},{-2,-3},{-2,3},{0,3},{0,5},{-10,5}};
tm5={{-10,-5},{10,-5},{10,4.5},{-0.75,4.5},{-0.75,3.5},{2,3.5},{2,-3},{-2,-3},{-2,3},{0.75,3},{0.75,5},{-10,5}};
tm6={{-10,-5},{10,-5},{10,7},{-9,4.5},{-9,3.5},{2,-2},{-2,-3},{-2,3},{9,3.5},{9,4.5},{-10,7}};
tm7={{-10,-5},{10,-5},{10,5},{.5,5},{-1,4},{.5,3},{-1,2},{.5,1},{-1,0},{.5,-1},{2,-1},{2,-3},{-2,-3},{-2,-1},{-.5,-1},{1,0},{-.5,1},{1,2},{-.5,3},{1,4},{-.5,5},{-10,5}};
tm8={{13876.088285207748`,13583.902501240373`},{13901.698801517487`,13628.228394724429`},{13919.968444108963`,13659.692779097706`},{13935.85636305809`,13687.496636971831`},{13963.85636305809`,13735.496636971831`},{13980.172897577286`,13764.05057232827`},{13998.918132781982`,13796.608086518943`},{14040.546700874964`,13868.696582235396`},{14060.004526236118`,13903.382270960472`},{14087.774329972268`,13945.03697647041`},{14106.99999988079`,14057.987787880003`},{14107.`,14051.3012342304`},{14051.902840881348`,13830.91259828031`},{13871.37843067944`,13861.`},{13874.793525728837`,13861.`},{14022.955277819834`,13838.205884293207`},{14115.38800375802`,13998.422609171696`},{14128.616750717163`,14021.82731544599`},{14159.856363117695`,14076.496637016535`},{14187.85636305809`,14124.496636971831`},{14203.167274781636`,14151.290732435882`},{13703.167274781636`,14151.290732435882`}};
tm9={{0,0},{2,0},{11,4},{-1,4},{8,1},{6,7},{7,0},{10,0},{10,6},{0,6}};
tm10={{0,0},{10,0},{10,6},{8,6},{-1,4},{7,2},{3,2},{11,4},{2,6},{0,6}};
tm11={{0,0},{2,0},{11,4},{-1,4},{4,0.5},{6,7},{7,0},{10,0},{10,6},{0,6}};

tms = {tm1, tm2, tm3, tm4, tm5, tm6, tm7, tm8, tm9, tm10, tm11};

First, we go along with @cvgmt go get the reg:
outerContour[points_]:=Module[{cb,reg,segs,fcs,mc,reg1,mc1,polys,segs1,tal},
cb=CoordinateBounds[points,.5];
reg=RegionDifference[BoundaryMesh[Rectangle@@Transpose@cb],Polygon@points];

Get rid of first four (those are from the rectangle), to get the intersected line segments:
segs=Drop[Sort@MeshCells[reg,1][[All,1]],4];

We turn these segments into an undirected graph; its FindFundamentalCycles give us a set of polygons which we can merge to get a non-intersecting polygon representation, which is then triangulated:
fcs=FindFundamentalCycles@Graph[UndirectedEdge@@@segs];
mc=MeshCoordinates@reg;
reg1=DiscretizeGraphics@Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonUnion[Polygon@#&/@(mc[[#]]&/@fcs[[All,All,1]])];
mc1=MeshCoordinates@reg1;
polys=MeshCells[reg1,2][[All,1]];

FInally, those triangles' segments are counted with Tally, so those that are only counted once, make up the boundary we are after:
segs1=Sort/@Flatten[Transpose[{#,RotateLeft@#}]&/@polys,1];
Partition[mc1[[Flatten[Pick[tal=Tally@segs1;tal[[All,1]],tal[[All,2]],1],1]]],2]
];

{Graphics@{Thread@Line@Transpose[{#,RotateLeft@#}]},Graphics@{Red,Thread@Line@Transpose[{outerC=outerContour[#];outerC,RotateLeft@outerC}]}}&/@tms


FindFundamentalCycles seems to do the job, though it's not obvious why it always generates cycles that cover 100% of any Polygon@points. But it does, in all my toy model cases.


UPD.
Based on @azerbajdzan solution, a bit cleaner:
contourPolygon1[x_] := 
 Polygon[#[[1]][[FirstCase[#[[2]], _List, #[[2]], All]]]] &@
  CrossingPolygon[x]

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Thread@Line@Transpose[{#, RotateLeft@#}], 
     FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[{Red}], contourPolygon1[#]}] & /@ tms //
  Multicolumn[#] &


